# Received company healthcare membership card, but I already refused the job

Tags: job-offer

I applied for two positions at different companies and ended up taking one instead of the other. I never officially accepted the job at company A (did not sign and return the offer of employment) and I called the recruiter to inform them of my decision.

I've now received a healthcare membership card a few *months* later, with my name and company A on it.

What am I required to do at this stage?

Comment: Is this in the USA? If so, you might add that tag.

Comment: Ask company A. They will probably tell you to send it back. It is of no value to you anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you definitely told them you were not taking the job, simply contact them, tell them you received a healthcare membership card in error and ask them if you need to return it or shred it or anything.

Addition: Depending on where you are you may want to keep records of your communications so that you're covered if someone tries to get you into trouble for this.

Comment: They will have already cancelled your coverage account anyway. But it's polite to ask them what they want done with the card.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to send a notification email to the HR like

Dear X,

I received the health card relating to your offer at your company. But I had not accepted the offer. Please do let me know if you would need the card or suggest alternative solutions. Thanks.